# How to use 'Return Value' parameter in Execute SQL task

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, return-value, execute-sql-task

I know there are 3 types of parameter in 'Parameter mapping' - Input Parameter, Output Parameter and Return Parameter. I understand how to use Input and Output parameter. But when I try to set the parameter type as 'Return Parameter', it doesn't work. Below is my SQL Server stored procedure.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spRandomReturn]
As 
Begin 
Return Convert(int, rand() * 10)
End
```

In SSIS Execute SQL task, I have set

1. connection type: OLE DB
2. parameter mapping: variable name: User::@random (I set SSIS a User parameter in SSIS: random INT32), Direction: ReturnValue, Type: Numeric, Parameter Name: @random
3. SQL statement:

   ```
    Declare @r int = @random EXEC @r = spRandomReturn
   ```

I created a return parameter in SSIS, but it doesn't work and throws error.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28419264/edit) your question to include the error message you get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using OLE DB Connection Manager, you need to use the `?` to indicate where parameters are.

Thus, your query becomes

```
EXECUTE ? = [dbo].[spRandomReturn]
```

And within your parameter mapping, you'd have

[image]

### Reproduction

Biml, the Business Intelligence Markup Language, describes the platform for business intelligence. Here, we're going to use it to describe the ETL. [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com), is a free add on for Visual Studio/BIDS/SSDT that addresses a host of shortcomings with it. Specifically, we're going to use the ability to transform a Biml file describing ETL into an SSIS package. This has the added benefit of providing you a mechanism for being able to generate exactly the solution I'm describing versus clicking through many tedious dialogue boxes.

You can see in the following bit of XML, I create a connection called CM_OLE and this points to localhost\dev2014 at tempdb. You would need to modify this to reflect your environment.

I create a package named so_28419264. This package contains 2 variables. One is `Query` which contains the first bit of code. The second is `ReturnValue` which we will use to capture the return value on the Mapping tab. I initialize this one to -1 as the provided stored procedure would never generate a negative value.

I add two Tasks, both Execute SQL Tasks. The second one does nothing, it simply serves as a point for me to put a breakpoint on. The first Execute SQL Task is where we invoke our Stored Procedure and assign the results into our variable

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <OleDbConnection Name="CM_OLE" ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost\dev2014;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;" />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package ConstraintMode="Linear" Name="so_28419264">
            <Variables>
                <Variable DataType="String" Name="Query">EXECUTE ? = [dbo].[spRandomReturn];</Variable>
                <Variable DataType="Int32" Name="ReturnValue">-1</Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <ExecuteSQL ConnectionName="CM_OLE" Name="SQL Demonstrate Return Value">
                    <VariableInput VariableName="User.Query" />
                    <Parameters>
                        <Parameter DataType="Int32" VariableName="User.ReturnValue" Name="0" Direction="ReturnValue" />
                    </Parameters>
                </ExecuteSQL>

                <ExecuteSQL ConnectionName="CM_OLE" Name="Put Breakpoint on me">
                    <DirectInput>SELECT 1;</DirectInput>                    
                </ExecuteSQL>                
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

### Results

It works

[image]